# A list of variables used by Wolfram Mathematica function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a way to get a list of variables used by a function?
For example:
    a=1;
    b=2;
    f[x_]:= 2a*x+b;

Needed:
    SomeFunction[f]

Output: 
    {{x},{a,b}}

The parameters of the function ({x}) are not really mandatory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the symbols (not necessarily variables) you could start with something like this:

```
DownValues[f]
```

which yields:

```
{HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> 2 a x + b}
```

The problem is then processing this in a way that you don't let Mathematica do the substitution.  This is done with `Hold`:

```
held=(Hold //@ DownValues[f][[1]])[[1, 2]]
```

which yields:

```
Hold[Hold[Hold[2] Hold[a] Hold[x]] + Hold[b]]
```

You can extract all the stuff that looks like a symbol with:

```
Cases[held, Hold[_Symbol], Infinity]
```

and you get:

```
{Hold[a], Hold[x], Hold[b]}
```

To make this a little nicer:

```
Union[Flatten[Hold @@ Cases[held, Hold[_Symbol], Infinity]]]
```

which gives you:

```
Hold[a, b, x]
```

You still need the `Hold`, because as soon as you lose it *Mathematica* will evaluate `a` and `b` and you'll lose them as symbols.

If you notice, it's considering `x` a symbol, which you may not want because it's a parameter.  You can tease the parameters out of the left side of the `DownValues[f][[1]]` `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) expression, and extract them, but I'll leave this detail to you.